# Atom Autocomplete Whitespace/Enclosing Tag

Tags: autocomplete, atom-editor

Autocomplete in Atom is generally great, but there is an issue I'm having that maybe you can help with. An example is shown in the image. Basically autocomplete doesn't seem to work when there is no whitespace after the query. The suggestion shows but pressing tab or return does nothing.

For example, here I make a 'li' tag (using autocomplete is fine here) but then want to put a anchor tag inside and autocomplete gives suggestions but doesn't work. Thus I have to do SPACE -> LEFTARROW -> TAB to use the autocomplete. Is there a way around this? Do others have the issue?

[image: issue]